# LockerService - dataset property on script tags doesn't work

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, aura, locker-service

When LockerService is enabled, execute the following code:

```
var test = document.createElement('script');
test.setAttribute('data-field-test', 'myTest');
console.log(test.dataset);
```

The `test.dataset` is `undefined`.

Try the same with a `div` element instead of a `script` tag. It works.
Try the same without LockerService enabled, it works.

I know you cannot inject script in LockerService to be executed, but at least, we should be able to use the script tag like any other DOM Element.

Any one have any workaround?

Answer (score 3):

The workaround is to use getAttribute(), for example `test.getAttribute("data-field-test")` which might be a little cumbersome if you want to get the entire set of data attributes on the element.

The underlying cause seems to be this: [SecureScriptElement](https://github.com/forcedotcom/aura/blob/master/aura-impl/src/main/resources/aura/locker/SecureScriptElement.js) does not have a dataset property defined on it. On the other hand [SecureElement](https://git.soma.salesforce.com/aura/aura/blob/master/aura-impl/src/main/resources/aura/locker/SecureElement.js#L1282) has it defined.
I will file a bug on our team to investigate if we can allow reading of "dataset" attribute on SecureScriptElement. Certainly SecureScriptElement is one of objects that has a very locked down api cause of security.

Comment: Thanks Ravi! The solution kind of don't work for me because I don't have the data attributes names in advance. A customer can put whatever field he wants in the `data-field-XYZ`.

Comment: Also @RaviJayaramappa , could you give me your bug tracking number. Thanks!

Comment: Ravi is on holiday and I just saw this - here is the bug W-3538484 tracking this work.

Comment: Thanks @DougChasman! When should we get the full support? Without this fix, I'll have to make multiple hacks (with the associated risk) in my code base for the Summer '17 release.